# Updating sub-menus variables

Tags: bash, unix

I have a problem with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
G=100

echo $G

main_menu()
{

    while :
    do
        clear

        echo "Select from menu"
        echo "[1] Press 1 to show savings"
        echo "[2] Press 2 to withdraw savings"
        echo "[3] Press 3 to exit"

        echo "Enter your menu choice [1-3]: \c "
        read -r  m_menu

        case "$m_menu" in
            1) option_1;;

            2) option_2;;

            3) exit 0;;

            *) echo "\nERROR: Please select a valid menu choice";
                echo "Press ENTER To Continue..." ; read ;;
        esac
    done
}

option_1()
{
    clear

    echo "Your balance is $G"

    echo "\nPress ENTER to return to menu..."  
    read

    return
}

option_2()
{
    clear

    echo "Withdraw savings"
    read -rp "Enter amount to withdraw: " num

    if [ $num -le $G ]; then
        answer=$(echo $(( G - num )))

        echo "Your new balance is: $answer"
        echo "$answer" | tee "$G"
    elif [ $num -gt $G ]; then
        echo "No: not eough money in your balance"
    fi

    read

    return
}

main_menu
```

---

The problem is the following: how do I make sure that once I withdraw savings, my saving count will be updated? Because if I withdraw $90, obviously when I return to the balance it should be $10 and yet this doesn't work for me (it still says saving balance is $100)

What can I do?

Thank you (sorry for my poor English)

Comment: **TL;DR** . Kindly format the question and put just enough information to reproduce the problem. Before posting,  I advice a [\[ **shellcheck** \]](http://shellcheck.net) too..

Answer (score 1):

You have to update G in your code.

```
if [ $num -le $G ]; then
   G=$(( G - num ))
   echo "Your new balance is: $G"
```